# SharePoint external facing site ability to go full site and non full site when accessed in mobile device

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, mobile

I've got an external site that's built in SharePoint 2007. the user of the site need to have an option to view the full site when accessed from a mobile device. I am thinking of just creating a button control to do this. The question is, what would be the best solution to do this? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend viewing the ful site in a mobile for some reasons

1. With all the junk HTML code that sharepoint produces I am not sure how it is going to look in a mobile device. This is the reason why we have the mobile view.
2. Because of the above reasons performance will be lower in a mobile device.

Adding a button or link is an option. Take a look at this page from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479269%28v=office.12%29.aspx) wich talks about mobile Pages which could be of some interest to you.